# Recovery Data from failed Raid Disk - NAS

Tags: raid, data-recovery, nas, testdisk

My Western Digital My World Book White Light NAS Drive stopped working.
This has a single 1TB Disk.

At first I started getting the following error:
Volume Status - Volume 'DataVolume' doesn't exist

Then the NAS refused to boot.

So I've removed the disk from the NAS and connected it to my Ubuntu laptop using a SATA to USB Cable.

Running TestDisk returns this :

Code:
Sat Apr 20 08:40:11 2013
Command line: TestDisk

```
TestDisk 6.11, Data Recovery Utility, April 2009
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org
OS: Linux, kernel 3.0.0-21-generic (#35-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 25 17:58:20 UTC 2012)
Compiler: GCC 4.5 - Oct 17 2010 20:12:36

ext2fs lib: 1.41.14, ntfs lib: 10:0:0, reiserfs lib: none, ewf lib: none

/dev/sda: LBA, HPA, LBA48, DCO support
/dev/sda: size       312581808 sectors
/dev/sda: user_max   312581808 sectors
/dev/sda: native_max 312581808 sectors
/dev/sda: dco        312581808 sectors

Warning: can't get size for Disk /dev/mapper/control - 0 B - CHS 1 1 1, sector size=512

Hard disk list
Disk /dev/sda - 160 GB / 149 GiB - CHS 19457 255 63, sector size=512 - ATA ST9160310AS
Disk /dev/sdb - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63, sector size=512 - WDC WD10 EARS-00MVWB0

Partition table type (auto): EFI GPT
Disk /dev/sdb - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - WDC WD10 EARS-00MVWB0
Partition table type: EFI GPT

Analyse Disk /dev/sdb - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
hdr_size=92
hdr_lba_self=1
hdr_lba_alt=1953525167 (expected 1953525167)
hdr_lba_start=34
hdr_lba_end=1953525134
hdr_lba_table=2
hdr_entries=128
hdr_entsz=128

check_part_gpt failed for partition
 1 P MS Reserved                   34     262177     262144 [Microsoft reserved partition]

Current partition structure:
No FAT, NTFS, EXT2, JFS, Reiser, cramfs or XFS marker
 1 P MS Reserved                   34     262177     262144 [Microsoft reserved partition]
 1 P MS Reserved                   34     262177     262144 [Microsoft reserved partition]

search_part()
Disk /dev/sdb - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63

recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=0/14, s_mnt_count=100/33, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=16352
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 489968
recover_EXT2: part_size 3919744
     MS Data                    64320    3984063    3919744
     EXT3 Sparse superblock, 2006 MB / 1913 MiB

Raid magic value at 247/254/8
Raid apparent size: 3919744 sectors
Raid chunk size: 0 bytes
md0 md 0.90.0 Raid 1: devices 0(8,1)*
     Linux Raid                 64320    3984191    3919872 [md0]
     md 0.90.0 Raid 1: devices 0(8,1)*, 2006 MB / 1914 MiB
     Linux Swap               3984192    4497967     513776
     SWAP2 version 1, 263 MB / 250 MiB

Raid magic value at 279/251/37
Raid apparent size: 513792 sectors
Raid chunk size: 0 bytes
md1 md 0.90.0 Raid 1: devices 0(8,2)*
     Linux Raid               3984192    4498111     513920 [md1]
     md 0.90.0 Raid 1: devices 0(8,2)*, 263 MB / 250 MiB

recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=0/7, s_mnt_count=82/23, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=7728
recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 246976
recover_EXT2: part_size 1975808
     MS Data                  4498176    6473983    1975808
     EXT3 Large file Sparse superblock, 1011 MB / 964 MiB

Raid magic value at 402/251/42
Raid apparent size: 1975808 sectors
Raid chunk size: 0 bytes
md3 md 0.90.0 Raid 1: devices 0(8,3)*
     Linux Raid               4498176    6474111    1975936 [md3]
     md 0.90.0 Raid 1: devices 0(8,3)*, 1011 MB / 964 MiB

Raid magic value at 402/254/45
Raid apparent size: 3733254810 sectors
MyBookWorld:2 md 1.x Raid 1 - Array Slot : 0 (0)
     Linux Raid               6474176 1953524869 1947050694 [MyBookWorld:2]
     md 1.x Raid 1 - Array Slot : 0 (0), 996 GB / 928 GiB

Results
     MS Data                    64320    3984063    3919744
     EXT3 Sparse superblock, 2006 MB / 1913 MiB
     Linux Raid                 64320    3984191    3919872 [md0]
     md 0.90.0 Raid 1: devices 0(8,1)*, 2006 MB / 1914 MiB
     Linux Swap               3984192    4497967     513776
     SWAP2 version 1, 263 MB / 250 MiB
     Linux Raid               3984192    4498111     513920 [md1]
     md 0.90.0 Raid 1: devices 0(8,2)*, 263 MB / 250 MiB
     MS Data                  4498176    6473983    1975808
     EXT3 Large file Sparse superblock, 1011 MB / 964 MiB
     Linux Raid               4498176    6474111    1975936 [md3]
     md 0.90.0 Raid 1: devices 0(8,3)*, 1011 MB / 964 MiB
   P Linux Raid               6474176 1953524869 1947050694 [MyBookWorld:2]
     md 1.x Raid 1 - Array Slot : 0 (0), 996 GB / 928 GiB
```

When I run testdisk the results table shows all the entries with a D in front of them, apart from the last one which has aP

I've done a deeper scan, that took all day..

and this is the result :

```
Disk /dev/sdb - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
Check the harddisk size: HD jumpers settings, BIOS detection...
The harddisk (1000 GB / 931 GiB) seems too small! (< 1965 GB / 1830 GiB)
The following partitions can't be recovered:
     MS Data                 67319776 2014370271 1947050496
     XFS 6.2+ - bitmap version, 996 GB / 928 GiB
     MS Data                128165104 2075215599 1947050496
     XFS 6.2+ - bitmap version, 996 GB / 928 GiB
     Mac HFS                128167720 2074956007 1946788288
     HFSX, 996 GB / 928 GiB
     Mac HFS                128190436 2074978723 1946788288
```

This goes on for thousands of lines........

Could someone please advise what this means and more importantly if my data is recoverable and how ??

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The disk is an XFS disk

en.wikipedia.org / wiki / XFS

Using either

NAS Data Recovery 
http://www.runtime.org/nas-recovery.htm

or 
Raise Data Recovery for XFS 5.8
http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Back-Up-and-Recovery/Raise-Data-Recovery-for-XFS.shtml

I can see my data.. Raise is only around £20.00 for a licence.
So that seems to be the way to go.

Hope this helps someone else.